# Сетевое приложение на C# без выделенного сервера

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Для учебы нужно создать игру по сети, уровень не выше вебсокетов. Пробовал на C#, но не могу придумать, как правильно построить приложение без сервера, так, чтобы каждый экземпляр мог выступать и клиентом, и сервером. Не могу даже определиться, куда нужно гуглить.

Comment: Сервер все равно есть, просто им выступает один из клиентов. Тот, кто создает игру, запускает сервер, остальные вводят его айпи (и порт) и подключается. Сервер может быть хоть отдельным экзешником, к которому сам клиент подключается по локалхосту.  
При этом сервер может быть и исключительно приемщиком-раздатчиком данных, но не производить никаких логических действий, а работать с данными будут клиенты, хотя проще, конечно, обрабатывать все в одном месте.

Comment: ... или все клиенты одновременно.

Comment: Просто это четкое требование от преподавателя: это должен быть один екзешник. Возникала мысль при старте приложения сделать попытку подключения, а если же получу отказ по таймауту - запустить сервер, но это костыль, кажется.

Comment: @thatside: А что мешает в одном исполнимом файле держать и сервер, и клиент? PS: требование глупое, да.

Comment: @VladD, впрочем, так и решил сделать. А вообще, есть ли возможность создать что-то по типу клиент-клиент? Вопрос уже чисто для интереса.

Comment: @thatside: ну, клиент должен же к кому-то приконнектиться? Вот этому самому кому-то и придётся быть сервером.

Comment: Можно организовывать сеть не клиент - сервер, а сеть из клиентов, организованных кольцом шиной или как еще угодно

Comment: Посмотрите, может сможете переделать под одно приложение: https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level3/3_2.php У меня тоже есть задача изменять ключи реестра на удаленном ПК, но так как примеров очень мало, не получается создать